# Refreshing plot in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, linear-regression, real-time

As part of displaying the progression of a linear regression model fit, I need to be able to update/refresh an xy plot. Below is a simple script for 3 sets of y data,  which need to be shown sequentially. However, they are piled up on top of each other. When fig.canvas.flush_events() is substituted with fig.clear() or fig.clf() the result is a blank plot. What am I - as a newbie -missing?

```
import torch as tc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tc.manual_seed(1)

X=tc.linspace(-3,3,30)

y0=X.pow(2)+0.5*tc.randn(X.shape[0])
y1=y0/1.3
y2=y0/1.6

y=[y0,y1,y2]


fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot()
ax.set_xlim(-3.3,3.3)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5,9.5)

for i in range(3):
    y_new=y[i]
    ax.plot(X,y_new,'db')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    plt.pause(1)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you are creating a new line every time you call `ax.plot`. The better way is to create a Line2D artist and to *update* the coordinates of the point in the loop:

(NB i've converted your example to using numpy instead of torch)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.linspace(-3, 3, 30)

y0 = np.power(X, 2) + 0.5 * np.random.randn(X.shape[0])
y1 = y0 / 1.3
y2 = y0 / 1.6

y = [y0, y1, y2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
l, = ax.plot(X, y0, 'db')
ax.set_xlim(-3.3, 3.3)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 9.5)


for i in range(3):
    y_new = y[i]
    l.set_ydata(y_new)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(1)

plt.show()
```

For this kind of things, you'd be better off using the `FuncAnimation` module provided by maptlotlib though:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np

X = np.linspace(-3, 3, 30)

y0 = np.power(X, 2) + 0.5 * np.random.randn(X.shape[0])
y1 = y0 / 1.3
y2 = y0 / 1.6

y = [y0, y1, y2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
l, = ax.plot(X, y0, 'db')
ax.set_xlim(-3.3, 3.3)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 9.5)


def animate(y_new):
    l.set_ydata(y_new)
    return l,


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func=animate, frames=y, interval=1000)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Diziet. Your comment about creating a new line (to be added on top of the previous ones) was Gold!! I now realize my folly. Thank you again!